# Few tutorial on CSS footers?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if there were any sites for designing the CSS footer..I have searched http://www.searchr.us/web-search.phtml?search=CSS+footers but i didn't get how to make one.

NOTE: I want to make a plain footer with a background.Thats it !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by designing you mean through basic CSS?

Just put things like:

```
    #footer {
        background-image: url("pathToImage");
        background-repeat: repeat; (if its a gradient)
    {
```

Not sure what else you would want if its only a "plain" background?

http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/web-roundups/inspiration-40-unique-footer-designs/

This link is brilliant

Answer (score 1):

http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/